# How to disconnect bluetooth LE device on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an application with bluetooth low energy under Windows 8.1 and working with microsoft bluetooth le stack. I almost finish with all routines, I implemented: connection, reconnection, detection connection/disconnection notifications, connection state check... but one thing left - disconnection.

So, how to disconnect connected device using C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, they didn't implement this function in windows sdk saying that it's better (in power consumption sense) to maintain connection than reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all ValueChanged events (-=)
2. Set all GattCharacteristic to null
3. Call Dispose on all Gatt Devices Services
4. Call dispose on the BluetoothLEDevice
5. Set the BluetoothLEDevice member to null
6. GC.Collect()
7. GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()